# What would be the best way to UV unwrap and texture this scene?

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there an easy way to unwrap and texture the walls in this scene?

[image: Screenshot of Scene]

Many of the faces are the same and can use the same texture space but is there an easy way to achieve that without having to manually assign seams and then aligning all the faces on the UV Map?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't say "many" faces are the same, some maybe are while others have different ratio and texture will look distorted if unwrapped the same. That being said, you can copy UV coordinates from one mesh / selected geometry piece to another with Magic UV addon, though make sure to copy them only on identical faces

Comment: This is generally achieved by using object instances for repeating elements instead of one huge mesh, so that if you do need to unwrap you only do it once. Also reaping the benefits of memory optimizations. You might however get away with generated texture coordinates for most orthogonal stuff at least.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question with some more specifics.  It's not clear what you consider the "walls" in your scene (e.g. does that include windows, moldings, etc.) and whether you're dealing with one mesh or multiple meshes, and with one material or multiple materials.  Also, were you planning on using simple tiled photo textures, or basic matte colors, or painting designs yourself, etc.?  If everything is one big mesh and you're not too worried about seamless tiling, you could select everything and do a "smart uv project" and texture paint the image texture manually.